# openTbs Tag not updating

Tags: php, ms-word, opentbs

I need to adjust background cell colors depending on adjacent cells.

My template is a word document and I set the cell color to some random color so my xml of interest looks like this:

```
<w:tc>
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="5400" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
      <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="D9D9D9" w:themeColor="background1" w:themeShade="D9"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="D9D9D9" w:themeFill="background1" w:themeFillShade="D9"/>
  </w:tcPr>
  <w:pPr><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr></w:pPr>
  <w:r>
  <w:rPr>
     <w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/>
   </w:rPr>
   <w:t>[title.bg;att=w:shd#w:fill][title.quoteFOB]</w:t>
  </w:r>
```

With the important points being:

- I have a w:shd tag with a wfill='D9D9D9' attribute assigned
- I have a [title.bg;att=w:shd#w:fill] entry in the template intended
  to route the merge block title.bg to the wfill attribute.
- I have a merge entry [title.quoteFOB] intended to route the merge
  field title.quoteFOB to the cell contents.

The call to perform the merge looks like this:

```
$TBS->MergeField('title', array('custName' => $custName, 
    'compName' => $compName, 'custAddress1' => $custAddr1, 
    'custAddress2' => $custAddr2, 'quoteNum' => $quoteNum, 
    'quoteRev' => $quoteRev, 'quoteForm' => $quoteForm, 
    'quoteExpDate' => $quoteExp, quoteTerms' => $quoteTerm, 
    'quoteFOB' => $quoteFob, bg'=>'00FF00'));
```

This is one of multiple merge blocks containing multiple cell updates all of which seem to work as expected. Everything except the cell color change.

I tried numerous things that could be causing the problem, like: disabling all but one merge, rearranging the order of the fields, and reading way to many stackoverflow entries.  None of which worked.

I assumed I was an idiot, and I could figure this out by looking at the code. and tracing through the code. What I found was that prior to the Show() call the TBS->Source was as expected. All merges took place and the w:fill value was substituted correctly in the modified XML.  But when I call

```
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, "$fileName.docx") and
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_STRING);
```

The output docx file does not contain the -w:fill change. Everything before it and after it, but not that change. Now I am back to thinking I am an idiot and I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?,  please help me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug. I tested your PHP and your XML and all was correctly merged. You can do only one Show() for each loaded template.  But I guess this is not the reason why only one field is not merged. Do you have other "att" parameters ? For which attribute target ? Can you send a piece of code to reproduce the bug ?

Answer (score 1):

It was not enough to just change the -w:fill attribute with '[title.bg;att=w:shd#w:fill]'. It appears that MS-Word ignored this attribute as long as -w:themeFill="background1" was there.  Once I added '[title.tf;att=w:shd#w:themeFill] to change the themeFill attribute to an empty string, everything worked as expected.

I am embarrassed how long it took me to take the step back and look at the output XML a second/third time. I hope that this helps anyone else avoid wasting as much time as I did.